# Terraform lambda function validation exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to set up my current infrastructure in Terraform (v 0.13.0). I am simply starting with migrating existing lambda functions. I have used the following code to try upload an existing lambda function in .net core 3.1 to AWS (provider v. 3.0). I have no issue to deploy this manually but this is obviously not the goal.

Here is the IAM role:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role_lambda" {
  name = "roleLambda"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""
      }
    ]
  }
  POLICY
  }
```

Below the function (note I have obfuscated some values):

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_tf" {
  function_name     = "LambdaTFTest"
  role              = aws_iam_role.role_lambda.arn
  handler           = "Lambda::Lambda.Function::FunctionHandler"
  runtime           = "dotnetcore3.1"
  s3_bucket         = "arn:aws:s3:::xxxx-xxxxxx"
  s3_key            = "Lambda.zip"
  s3_object_version = "XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx"
}
```

However I keep getting this error as an output with no more details:

```
Error: Error creating Lambda function: ValidationException: 
        status code: 400, request id: a5e89c38-d1f1-456d-93c1-41650fb45386
```

I already made sure that my lambda is deployed within the same region as the s3 bucket itself so this is not the issue. I thought this could be related to some invalid parameters but I have played with all of them and can't manage to find the problem. I have also double checked the correct spelling of the key, version and so on. How can I make progress on this ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Open AWS console, navigate to CloudFormation->Stacks and check why your lambda stack is not executed properly.

Comment: Since this is Terraform, it won't appear in the CloudFormation console.

Answer (score 10):

This issue is caused by low values of timeout or using role name instead of role ARN. I changed from:

```
role = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.name
```

to

```
role = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
```

And the function deployment was successful.

Answer (score 5):

The `aws_iam_role` has a **syntax error**. There is missing `-` in front of `POLICY` if you want it to keep it tabbed:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role_lambda" {
  name = "roleLambda"

  assume_role_policy = <<-POLICY
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""
      }
    ]
  }
  POLICY
}
```

In `aws_lambda_function`, the `s3_bucket` should be just bucket name, **not its** arn:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_tf" {
  function_name     = "LambdaTFTest"
  role              = aws_iam_role.role_lambda.arn
  handler           = "Lambda::Lambda.Function::FunctionHandler"
  runtime           = "dotnetcore3.1"
  s3_bucket         = "xxxx-xxxxxx" 
  s3_key            = "Lambda.zip"
  s3_object_version = "XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to one of the parameters being passed in being invalid.

Ensure that the Lambda name is unique, the S3 bucket and key exist and that the IAM role has the assume role policy when it’s attached.

The runtime is correct, everything else is user defined so would need you to validate.

Try using [filename](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#filename) property instead of S3 (this will use local disk instead of S3). Does that work? If so it might be S3 permissions.

If you verify everything and it’s still not working the best suggestion would be to raise with AWS support providing the request ID.

Answer (score 1):

It could really be any of the parameters you pass to lambda resource. In my case I said the timeout was "900000" instead of 900. I assumed it to be in ms for some reason.

Comment: Badly formatted subnets in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the name of lambda function. I was using spacing and its not allowed.

Comment: Ah! This was it, Lambda naming conventions. In my case using dots in the version (v0.1). Removed, sorted. Good spot!

Answer (score 1):

The `s3_bucket` should only include the name, like `xxxx-xxxxxx`

The following formats are wrong:

`arn:aws:s3:::xxxx-xxxxxx` or
`s3://xxxx-xxxxxx`

Comment: i had this exact problem. I was using "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxxxxx" but changed to just "xxxxxxxxxxxxx and i was able to deploy my lambda func

Answer (score 0):

I actually got the same error when using a docker image. The fix here is to set  the package_type  = "Image"

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the lambda description being too long.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with allocating memory more than 4096 so if you copy the example from the terraform docs it will fail.
This does not happen on all AWS account but on some

Answer (score 0):

As this is the top hit on Google for "Terraform Lambda ValidationException", I'll just drop here that I had a list of subnets that was too long. For what it's worth, perhaps it will help someone!

Answer (score -1):

For those who might have run into the same issue, it might help to try formatting your `main.tf` file by converting all spaces to tabs.

If you're using vscode, there is a tab below to convert this, depends if spaces or tabs

Below:

[image]

Convert Indentation to Tabs:
[image]

This fixed the issue for me.